# Motools HTMLTable Sort - Secondary sorting

Tags: mootools

I'm trying to sort a table which can have more than 2 columns (Datetime, Name, Email etc.)

I'm using mootools HTMLTable sort to sort the columns. But when I sort on Name, none of the other columns are sorted. How would it be possible to make a secondary sort column work ?

Example : (When I sort on the name column, the datetime column goes out of wack)

```
5/08/2014 09:51:18 AM  | Adam |   adam123@gmail.com
5/12/2014 03:51:28 PM  | Adam |   adam123@gmail.com
5/10/2014 04:51:38 AM  | Adam |   adam123@gmail.com
5/07/2014 04:23:21 AM  | Adam |   adam123@gmail.com
5/11/2014 06:51:48 PM  | Dave |   dave123@gmail.com
5/09/2014 10:51:58 AM  | Dave |   dave123@gmail.com
```

I tried doing a secondary sort with the datetime column but nothing happens.

HTML :

```
<table id="report_table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
      <th>Date/time</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>5/08/2014 09:51:18 AM</td>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>adam123@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5/12/2014 03:51:28 PM</td>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>adam123@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5/10/2014 04:51:38 AM</td>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>adam123@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5/07/2014 04:23:21 AM</td>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>adam123@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5/11/2014 06:51:48 PM</td>
        <td>Dave</td>
        <td>dave123@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5/09/2014 10:51:58 AM</td>
        <td>Dave</td>
        <td>dave123@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript :

```
var sortableTable = new HtmlTable($('report_table'), {sortable: true,     sortIndex : 1});
sortableTable.sort(0, false, false);
```

EDIT : Added HTML as well. If I just sort by the datetime column, it sorts fine, but it doesn't do well only if the secondary sort is on date/time.

Any help would really help.

Comment: could you please post your HTML also?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `sortIndex` option and use `sort` method to specify primary and secondary sort, as described in the [documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/HtmlTable.Sort#HtmlTable%3asort). Mootools will remember sort options for columns even after the user clicks on thead to resort the table.

```
var sortableTable = new HtmlTable( $('report_table'), { sortable: true } );
sortableTable.sort( 0, false, true );
sortableTable.sort( 1, false, false );
```